# Devexpress GridLookup autopostback false causing page load

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using `ASPxGridLookup` control and I set `AutoPostBack="false"` for that control, but when I changed the value the normal page life cycle is getting executed what is the solution for this.

`<dx:ASPxGridLookup ID="ASPxGridLookup1" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID" AutoPostBack="false">
        </dx:ASPxGridLookup>`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dtLookup = new DataTable();
            dtLookup.Columns.Add("ID");
            dtLookup.Columns.Add("Name");
            dtLookup.Rows.Add("1", "Dorababu");
            dtLookup.Rows.Add("2", "Vivekh");
            ASPxGridLookup1.DataSource = dtLookup;
            ASPxGridLookup1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set AutoPostBack to false, changing ASPxGridLookup value initiates callback, not postback. Callback is a special kind of postback that skips some of lifecycle events and doesn't update ViewState.

[DevEx: Discussion about Page.IsPostBack and Page.IsCallback values](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q483006)
[DevEx: The Concept of Callbacks](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18387)
[Difference between a Postback and a Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365100/difference-between-a-postback-and-a-callback)